# Check if there are any table in database

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, database, jdbc

I want to do the same as in the answers to this question:
[Check if table exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942788/check-if-table-exists)
but I want to check if any table exist, not just a particular table and not iterating through table names, I mean if there's any table at all in the database.
According to the API, the third argument of getTables(),

> tableNamePattern - a table name pattern; must match the table name as it is stored in the database

So it seems the tableName should match exactly in the database. Is there a better way to find if any table exist in the database? Or I really have to loop through an array of table names and call:

```
getConnection().getMetaData().getTables(null, null, "table", null).next();
```

each iteration?

Comment: The answer from the link you provided (the choosen one) has what you are asking. `meta.getTables(null, null, null, new String[] "TABLE"});` Then you just iterate through it.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Actually the third parameter should be `"%"`. JDBC isn't entirely clear if `null` is supposed to work for this parameter and some drivers won't work if null is specified for this parameter.

Comment: The accepted answer in the question you link to will return all tables (at least: in some, but not all drivers, otherwise see my previous comment).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel sounds like you need to add your comment to the accepted answer on the duplicate that you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine if any tables exist by querying the table `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`:

```
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```

If you want to look for a particular pattern in a name, you can add a `where` clause:

```
WHERE table_name like YOURPATTERNHERE
```

Answer (score 1):

To compliment a little more, use IF EXISTS() like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%MY TABLE%')
BEGIN
     --Do Something here
END
```