# List all the tables in a database

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, ucanaccess

I am using ***ucanaccess*** to manage a SQL database in Java.
I've done Initial setup using the answer from the question - [setting up ucanaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc)

After setting up, I am successfully able to ***Create Tables, Insert into Tables*** however, I am not able to list the existing tables.

I'm attaching the code that I'm using -

```
public class Driver {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Connection myconnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess:///usr/local/var/mysql/library/database.accdb");
        Statement stmt = myconnection.createStatement();

        stmt.executeQuery("create table books ( BarCode VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, author VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY kEY (BarCode) );");
        stmt.executeQuery("Insert INTO books VALUES(\"123\", \"Monk\", \"Robin\")");
        ResultSet res = myconnection.getMetaData().getTables(null, null, "books", new String[] {"TABLE"});
        while (res.next()) {
            System.out.println(
                    "   "+res.getString("TABLE_CAT")
                            + ", "+res.getString("TABLE_SCHEM")
                            + ", "+res.getString("TABLE_NAME")
                            + ", "+res.getString("TABLE_TYPE")
                            + ", "+res.getString("REMARKS"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The part that is listing all the table names is used from the answer - [List all the tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942788/check-if-table-exists)

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:** I was trying to check if **"books"** existed in database, hence I had given **"books"** in ***tableNamePattern*** field in search. After pointing out by  @Andreas, I've modified it.

Comment: Instead of only trying to list tables named `books`, try listing *all* tables, like your question actually says, by replacing `"books"` with `"%"`

Comment: I would guess, that ddl statements like `CREATE TABLE` are not allowed in `executeQuery` - but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Oh right. You have to use `executeUpdate` instead of `executeQuery` for modification of the database. Good catch by slartidan

Comment: @AKSW  Indeed using **executeQuery** was the main Issue. I changed it will **executeUpdate** and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @slartidan Thanks to you too!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @AKSW, I should've used **executeUpdate** instead of **executeQuery**.

In the Examples [here](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html#examples) the commands to use different functions is specified for DDL & Queries.