# Check if a table exists using Java

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset, database-metadata

I am trying to perform a check on the database for a table using the below snippet:
But the problem is, if the table or the view is empty the condition tables.next() does not evaluate to true, how to handle this scenario?

```
DatabaseMetaData dbm = con.getMetaData();
ResultSet tables = dbm.getTables(null, null, "your_table_name", null);
if (tables.next()) {
  // Table exists
}
else {
  // Table does not exist
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if table exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942788/check-if-table-exists)

Comment: These are very trivial questions please do a basic search before posting questions

Comment: If `next()` returns `false`, then the table does not exist. If the table or view is empty, then `next()` will still return `true`, because the table exists. Could you be more specific as to what the problem is? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel , thanks for the inputs. Found out that the problem was with the SQL statement referring to the incorrect schema. The code is working as expected.